# How to select multiple dates from UserControl calendar in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, calendar

I have one userForm Calendar Control in Excel which works fine for a single date. Here is the code:

```
 If Range("C4").Value = "" Then
    ' do nothing'
 Else
    If IsDate(Range("C4").Value) = True Then
       Load frmCustomCalendarControl
       frmCustomCalendarControl.SelectedDayNumber = Day(Range("C4").Value)
       frmCustomCalendarControl.SelectedMonthNumber = Month(Range("C4").Value)
       frmCustomCalendarControl.SelectedYearNumber = Year(Range("C4").Value)
    End If
 End If
 frmCustomCalendarControl.Show
 If frmCustomCalendarControl.SelectedDayNumber = 0 And _
  frmCustomCalendarControl.SelectedMonthNumber = 0 And _
  frmCustomCalendarControl.SelectedYearNumber = 0 Then
    ' user click on the cancel button in the calendar control therefore do nothing '
 Else
    Range("C4").Value = DateSerial(frmCustomCalendarControl.SelectedYearNumber, _
     frmCustomCalendarControl.SelectedMonthNumber, _
     frmCustomCalendarControl.SelectedDayNumber)
    ' the following properties are also available from the customer control if you need them
    Debug.Print "frmCustomCalendarControl.SelectedDateDDMMYYYY = " & frmCustomCalendarControl.SelectedDateDDMMYYYY
    Debug.Print "frmCustomCalendarControl.SelectedDayString = " & frmCustomCalendarControl.SelectedDayString
    Debug.Print "frmCustomCalendarControl.SelectedMonthString = " & frmCustomCalendarControl.SelectedMonthString
    Debug.Print "frmCustomCalendarControl.SelectedYearString = " & frmCustomCalendarControl.SelectedYearString
 End If
 Unload frmCustomCalendarControl
```

This is the code to Run calendar UserForm and select the date. 
Now I want to select multiple dates using the same user Control.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what calendar control you use. I cannot find any calendar control having properties which are seen in your code. For testing purposes I created a MonthView control. In the properties of MonthView you can see:

- `MaxSelCount`, which represents the maximum number of days to select;
- `MultiSelect` - if it's `True`, you can have more than 1 date selected.

[image]

Comment: since Calendar control and month view control is not supported by all the version of excel i have made my own calendar using labels and toggle buttons

Comment: could you share a screenshot so that we could imagine the situation better?